# Error when builiding openCV with MacPorts

Tags: c++, c, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to build openCV with MacPorts.
I followed [this procedure](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_OpenCV_Port).
Who can help me?
Thanx.

This is the output:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for opencv..........................................................................
--->  Dependencies to be installed: bzip2 cmake libidn gettext expat libiconv gperf ncurses ncursesw openssl zlib dirac cppunit autoconf help2man p5.12-locale-gettext perl5.12 m4 perl5 perl5 perl5 automake libtool faac faad2 ffmpeg XviD gmake lame libogg libsdl xorg-libXext pkgconfig glib2 xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-libXau xorg-xproto xorg-libXdmcp xorg-libxcb python27 db46 gdbm python_select readline sqlite3 python27 xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto libxml2 xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto xrender xorg-renderproto libtheora libvorbis libvpx yasm schroedinger orc speex texi2html x264 liboil
--->  Installing bzip2 @1.0.6_0
**Error: Target org.macports.install returned: /usr/bin/tar: invalid option -- q
Try `/usr/bin/tar --help' for more information.**
Warning: the following items did not execute (for bzip2): org.macports.activate org.macports.install
**Error: Failed to install bzip2**
Log for bzip2 is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_archivers_bzip2/bzip2/main.log

Error: The following dependencies were not installed: bzip2 cmake libidn gettext expat libiconv gperf ncurses ncursesw openssl zlib dirac cppunit autoconf help2man p5.12-locale-gettext perl5.12 m4 perl5 perl5 perl5 automake libtool faac faad2 ffmpeg XviD gmake lame libogg libsdl xorg-libXext pkgconfig glib2 xorg-libX11 xorg-bigreqsproto xorg-inputproto xorg-kbproto xorg-libXau xorg-xproto xorg-libXdmcp xorg-libxcb python27 db46 gdbm python_select readline sqlite3 python27 xorg-libpthread-stubs xorg-xcb-proto libxml2 xorg-util-macros xorg-xcmiscproto xorg-xextproto xorg-xf86bigfontproto xorg-xtrans xorg-libXrandr xorg-randrproto xrender xorg-renderproto libtheora libvorbis libvpx yasm schroedinger orc speex texi2html x264 liboil
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Comment: Did you execute `sudo port install opencv` or just `port install opencv`?

Comment: It's not that difficult to see that bzip2 failed to install, you should change the title of your question.

Comment: I execute sudo port install opencv. I have the same error if I execute sudo port install cmake. The error is :Error: Target org.macports.install returned: /usr/bin/tar: invalid option -- q
Try `/usr/bin/tar --help' for more information.
Is Tar the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Something is the matter with your /usr/bin/tar program. It is either ancient (from a much earlier version of OS X than you are running), and/or you replaced it with GNU tar (it's supposed to be BSD tar). See existing MacPorts tickets:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30969

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/31773

Either way, restore /usr/bin/tar from your backups, or if you have no backups, or your backups also contain the wrong tar, reinstall the OS.